# Get input form Ionic 2, Typescript, Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

New to building with Angular 2 and Typescript, I'm trying to do something I do very frequently otherwise which is collect information from input form which in this case is the email.

Now I couldn't use `var x = document.getElementById("email").value;` because Typescript gave an error so I went and used this instead `var x = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("email")).value;` but now I get `undefined`, my HTML is as such:

```
 <div class="padding" style="text-align:center;">
    <ion-list>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" id="email"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="password"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

    </ion-list>
 </div>
```

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use view child to get element instead of pure js. 
E.g

```
@(ViewChild) yourElement;
```

And in your html instead of id pass `#yourElement` and you should be able to access the value of that element.

Comment: Not very well explained, however worked once I also read through this http://learnangular2.com/viewChild/